# React/Redux: why is my action not being called in ComponentDidMount()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, components, action

I'm trying to get a method to load on page load and I found the best way to do this is by using ComponentDidMount(). I can't seem to get it to fire my method. I know that CompoentDidMount() is working tho because I was able to get logging in it.

Here's my ComponentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.getStus()
}
```

And here's my mapToDispatch and Connect:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return{
    getStus: () => dispatch(auth.getStus),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

Here's my action code:

```
export const getStus = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log("In getStus");
        let headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
        return fetch(`${url}/api/stu/list/`, {headers, body: "", method: "GET"})
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status < 500) {
                    return res.json().then(data => {
                        return {status: res.status, data};
                    })
                } else {
                    throw res;
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    dispatch({type: 'GET_STUS_SUCCESSFUL'});
                    return res.data;
                } else if (res.status === 403 || res.status === 401) {
                    dispatch({type: "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR", data: res.data});
                    throw res.data;
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: provide reducer and actions code as well

Comment: @AnilKumar The code isn't even getting there

Comment: @AnilKumar I just added it tho

Comment: check if `auth.getStus` is actually a function. Your code doesn't show how you are importing the action.

Comment: @MichaelGutz I'm importing it. I just didn't add that snippet to the code. I have eslint on to catch things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
 return{
    getStus: () => dispatch(auth.getStus),
   }
}
```

to

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return{
    getStus: () => dispatch(auth.getStus()),
   }
}
```